# How do I set a variable in a makefile from a CmakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

This is a very simple question.

In the following [tutorial](https://code.litomisky.com/2014/03/09/how-to-have-multiple-versions-of-the-same-library-side-by-side/) the author gives us a Makefile file in which the variable `CPPFLAGS` is set. Depending on that the machine knows what library to include.

I want to do the same, but I work with Cmake, so I don't write Makefiles, only `CMakeLists.txt` files.

My question is, how do I define this variable in the CMakeLists file to have it in the Makefile?

Comment: Maybe you want target_compile_options() or add_compile_options()?

Comment: In the linked tutorial you would certainly not use the `CPPFLAGS` in the same manner as it  is in the examples. `CMake` has support for compiler and linker settings that you would set instead of such a variable. target_include_directories(), target_link_librararies() ...

Comment: Using CMake to build your own project you shouldn't use any of the approaches described on the linked page (assuming my assumptions are correct). OpenCV should provide configuration scripts after being installed; you should be able to directly use those to get access to imported opencv targets which automatically apply all necessary settings to a target linking them via `target_link_libraries`. `set(MY_OPENCV_CONFIG trunk CACHE STRING "opencv config to use") find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED CONFIG PATHS "/home/krystof/libs/opencv-${MY_OPENCV_CONFIG}/release/installed")`

Comment: Not sure about the actual name of the imported targets though and if you need to specify the components to import for `find_package`. Also note that this is just an educated guess after a short look at the opencv repo; I haven't worked with OpenCV in this way before. If you wonder about the `set(... CACHE ...)` btw: that's just a variable with a default value that could be overwritten during configuration using `-D MY_OPENCV_CONFIG=2.4.8` from the command line. Note that you need to set up a new build directory to change the opencv version used or delete the cache to change the opencv version